# Lists of dropdown search menues are not dropping where they should

Tags: php, javascript, html, css, ajax

I have 4 dependent search dropdown menues next to each other. I have two issues:

1. When I press a key in any of the drop-menues, the mysql-connected lists drop but not underneath the actual 'input-type-search-box'.
2. Also when I e.g. press a key in the first menue, the other menues move underneath the dropped list but the menues/'input-type-search-boxes' shall actually remain fixed next to each other.

This might only be a simple css-issue, but I cant get it work for quite a while now trying many things, so I posted it. Thanks for your help!

Here is the code: HTML

```
<input type="text" class="autosuggest" id="autosuggest1" placeholder="Select Continent...">
    <div class="type">
        <ul class="result" id="result1"></ul>
    </div>
<input type="text" class="autosuggest" id="autosuggest2" placeholder="Select Country...">
    <div class="type">
        <ul class="result" id="result2"></ul>
    </div>
<input type="text" class="autosuggest" id="autosuggest3" placeholder="Select Area...">
    <div class="type">
    <ul class="result" id="result3"></ul>
    </div>
<input type="text" class="autosuggest" id="autosuggest4" placeholder="Select Category...">
    <div class="type">
    <ul class="result" id="result4"></ul>
    </div>
```

CSS

```
    #search_line{
        margin-top: 20px;
        display: inline;
    }
.autosuggest, .type, .result{
    width: 150px;
}
#autosuggest1{
    padding: 4px;
    border: 1px solid blue;
    background: white;
    float: left;
}
#autosuggest2{
    padding: 4px;
    border: 1px solid blue;
    background: white;
    float: left;
}
#autosuggest3{
    padding: 4px;
    border: 1px solid blue;
    background: white;
    float: left;
}
#autosuggest4{
    padding: 4px;
    border: 1px solid blue;
    background: white;
    float: left;
}
.result{
    width: 150px;
    list-style: none;
}
.result li{
    padding:5px;
    border:1px solid #000;
    border-top: 0;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

JS

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
$('#autosuggest1').keyup(function() {
    var continent = $(this).attr('value');
    $.post('php/dropdown.php', {continent:continent},  function(data) {
        $('#result1').html(data);

        $('.result li').click(function() {
            var result_value = $(this).text();
            $('#autosuggest1').attr('value', result_value);
            $('#result1').html('');
        });
    });
});

$('#autosuggest2').keyup(function() {
    var country = $(this).attr('value');
    $.post('php/dropdown.php', {country:country}, function(data) {
        $('#result2').html(data);

        $('.result li').click(function() {
            var result_value = $(this).text();
            $('#autosuggest2').attr('value', result_value);
            $('#result2').html('');
        });
    });
});

$('#autosuggest3').keyup(function() {
    var area = $(this).attr('value');
    $.post('php/dropdown.php', {area:area}, function(data) {
        $('#result3').html(data);

        $('.result li').click(function() {
            var result_value = $(this).text();
            $('#autosuggest3').attr('value', result_value);
            $('#result3').html('');
        });
    });
});

$('#autosuggest4').keyup(function() {
    var category = $(this).attr('value');
    $.post('php/dropdown.php', {category:category}, function(data) {
        $('#result4').html(data);

        $('.result li').click(function() {
            var result_value = $(this).text();
            $('#autosuggest4').attr('value', result_value);
            $('#result4').html('');
            $('#result4').focusout('');
        });
    });
});

});
```

And here also PHP

```
<?php
include '../core/db/connectdropdown.php';

if (isset($_POST['continent']) == true && empty($_POST['continent']) == false) {
$continent = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['continent']);
$query = mysql_query("SELECT DISTINCT `continent` FROM `area` WHERE `continent` LIKE   '$continent%'");
while (($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) !== false) {
    echo '<li>', $row['continent'], '</li>';
}   
}

if (isset($_POST['country']) == true && empty($_POST['country']) == false) {
$country = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['country']);
$query = mysql_query("SELECT DISTINCT `country` FROM `area` WHERE `country` LIKE     '$country%'");
while (($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) !== false) {
    $dbcountry = $row['country'];

}   
}

if (isset($_POST['area']) == true && empty($_POST['area']) == false) {
$area = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['area']);
$query = mysql_query("SELECT DISTINCT `area` FROM `area` WHERE `area` LIKE '$area%'");
while (($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) !== false) {
    echo '<li>', $row['area'], '</li>';
}   
}

if (isset($_POST['category']) == true && empty($_POST['category']) == false) {
$category = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['category']);
$query = mysql_query("SELECT `category` FROM `categories` WHERE `category` LIKE '$category%'");
while (($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) !== false) {
    echo '<li>', $row['category'], '</li>';
}   
}

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you might have some JavaScript problems as well. Is your script appending the results for the list by ID or by class? Just curious.

I'm not seeing any apparent problems with the CSS and HTML you posted but I tried changing the HTML and CSS structure a bit in this fiddle. Maybe it improves things for you:

http://jsfiddle.net/w8zG6/

What happens if you use my CSS/HTML. Do you get better results? (worse perhaps?)

If this isn't helping could you post your JavaScript that handles creating the menus?

**Edit:**

There seems like there might be a problem in your PHP:

In your other Ajax handler code blocks you have this:

```
echo '<li>', $row['continent'], '</li>';
```

Whereas your country handling code has this:

```
$dbcountry = $row['country'];
```

Try replacing that line with the following:

```
echo '<li>', $row['country'], '</li>';
```

Comment: Thanks Matthew, yeah still the same. Here is my js. You prob. right, it must be somethng else as I also think I tried everything in css.

Comment: Not sure why I didn't think of it before but can you post HTML source the of the drop down after you select something from the menu as well.